# Twitter Authentication - NO PIN codebird

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am having issues with authenticating! I get 401 with the following code

```
<script src="codebird.js"></script>
<script>
var cb          = new Codebird;
cb.setConsumerKey("xxx", "xxx");
function autht(){
    cb.__call(
        "oauth_requestToken",
        {oauth_callback: "http://snipleecast.com/index2.php"},
        function (reply,rate,err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error response or timeout exceeded" + err.error);
            }
            if (reply) {
                // stores it
                cb.setToken(reply.oauth_token, reply.oauth_token_secret);

                // gets the authorize screen URL
                cb.__call(
                    "oauth_authorize",
                    {},
                    function (auth_url) {
                        window.codebird_auth = window.open(auth_url);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );  
}

<?php if ( isset ( $_GET['oauth_verifier'] ) ){
    ?>

        // assign stored request token parameters to codebird here
        // ...
        cb.setToken(something, something2);

        cb.__call(
            "oauth_accessToken",
            {
                oauth_verifier: '<?php echo $_GET['oauth_verifier']; ?>'
            },
            function (reply, rate, err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error response or timeout exceeded" + err.error);
                }
                if (reply) {
                    cb.setToken(reply.oauth_token, reply.oauth_token_secret);
                    alert('<?php echo $_GET['oauth_verifier']; ?>');
                }

                // if you need to persist the login after page reload,
                // consider storing the token in a cookie or HTML5 local storage
            }
        );
    <?php
}
?>
```

I click a button, and it launches the twitter oauth page fine, but once it returns to my homepage, nothing happens :( Just 401 error.

IDK what I am doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind sorry guys figured it out! Looks like I was missing

```
"oauth_accessToken",
            {
                oauth_token: '<?php echo $_GET['oauth_token']; ?>',
                oauth_verifier: '<?php echo $_GET['oauth_verifier']; ?>'
            },
```